# Doctrine COALESCE, SUM and Subtract results in Syntax Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '-'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to subtract the `SUM` of two fields from each other. Therefore I need to use `COALESCE`, because when there are no results in one field, the `SUM` returns null for both. However this specific query apparently returns a syntax error:

**TagGroup**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TagGroupRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="tag_group")
     */
    class TagGroup
    {
      ...
       /**
       * The collection of $votes that this tag group has
       * @var ArrayCollection $votes
       * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Vote\TagVote", cascade={ "persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="tagGroup")
       */
       private $votes;

       /**
        * The collection of $rewards that this tag group has
        * @var ArrayCollection $votes
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag\TagGroupReward", cascade={ "persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="tagGroup")
        */
       private $rewards;
        ..
    }
```

**TagGroupRepository**

```
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("tg")
                ->select('COALESCE(SUM(ve.amountYp), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(r.amountYp), 0)')
                ->leftJoin('tg.votes', 'v')
                ->leftJoin('tg.rewards', 'r')
                ->leftJoin('v.entries', 've')
                ->where("tg.id = :tagGroupId")
                ->setParameter("tagGroupId", $group->getId());
```

> Error [0]: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 37: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '-' in file/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/yoors/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 54 [] []

However if I remove the first `COALESCE` the query does work. Notice:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("tg")
                    ->select('SUM(ve.amountYp) - COALESCE(SUM(r.amountYp), 0)')
                    ->leftJoin('tg.votes', 'v')
                    ->leftJoin('tg.rewards', 'r')
                    ->leftJoin('v.entries', 've')
                    ->where("tg.id = :tagGroupId")
                    ->setParameter("tagGroupId", $group->getId());
```

This is not enough for me, because when `SUM(ve.amountYp)` returns null I have the same problem. What is the correct syntax for what I want to achieve?

Comment: Enlighten me, You don't need a FROM?

Comment: @P.Salmon, No since I use query builder from the repository belonging to the Entity itself. with $this->createquerybuilder it implies that the from already concerns TagGroup Entity. I'll update my question with the Repository and Entity